# I have two geometries that should be identical but they're not. Where is the difference?

Tags: postgis

I have two geometries that appear identical when I use `st_asewkt`, but `ST_Equals` returns `false`.

```
SELECT st_asewkt(tb1.geom), st_asewkt(tb2.geom)
FROM
(SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000004000000606E3D4100000000502156410400000040703D4100000000502156410400000040703D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry as geom) tb1,
(SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000000000000606E3D4100000000502156410000000040703D4100000000502156410000000040703D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry as geom) tb2
```

Returns:

```
"SRID=2193;MULTIPOLYGON(((1928800 5801280,1929280 5801280,1929280 5800560,1928800 5800560,1928800 5801280)))"   
"SRID=2193;MULTIPOLYGON(((1928800 5801280,1929280 5801280,1929280 5800560,1928800 5800560,1928800 5801280)))"
```

This following query returns `FALSE`:

```
"PostgreSQL 9.6.17, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit"
"POSTGIS="2.5.3 r17699" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.0 3.7.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER"

SELECT st_equals(tb1.geom, tb2.geom)
FROM
(SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000004000000606E3D4100000000502156410400000040703D4100000000502156410400000040703D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry as geom) tb1,
(SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000000000000606E3D4100000000502156410000000040703D4100000000502156410000000040703D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry as geom) tb2
```

I tried this query to make them match:

```
SELECT st_equals(ST_SnapToGrid(tb1.geom,0.01), ST_SnapToGrid(tb2.geom,0.01))
FROM
(SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000004000000606E3D4100000000502156410400000040703D4100000000502156410400000040703D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry as geom) tb1,
(SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000000000000606E3D4100000000502156410000000040703D4100000000502156410000000040703D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry as geom) tb2
```

It also returned `false`. However, I tried this query again in PostGIS 3.0, and it returned `true`, which is great, but I need it to work in PostGIS 2.5.3.
Can anyone see the difference? And why does the final query work in PostGIS 3.0 but not PostGIS 2.5.3?

Comment: There is a ...0004000... in your first geometry. I guess `ST_Equals` does not convert to ewtk for comparison. Can you update to PostGIS 3.0?

Comment: I saw that, but I'm unsure how to determine what that '0004000' is indicating, as all the points in the geometry are the same, and the projection. Ideally I would upgrade but I'm in a corporate environment so its not that straightforward. Therefore the initial goal is to figure out how to resolve this in PostGIS 2.5.3.

Comment: The conversion to a fixed length WKT representation from WKB/bytea is subject to floating point rounding errors; `ST_Equals` operates on the storage type (with floating point precision), and those geometries *are* different! When snapping (especially with a rather large tolerance) may in fact enlargen the difference, if the coordinates are rounded to different limits (check the WKT for the snapped geometries).

Comment: Weird. The original geometries are not equal because they have corner coordinates as `(1928800 5801280) vs. (1928800.000000001 5801280)` but I verified that ST_SnapToGrid in PostGIS 2.5 does the job correctly and snaps coordinates into `(1928800 5801280)`. The order of vertices in the multipolygons after ST_SnapToGrid is the same (if that even matters) so ST_Equals should in my mind return true.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I thought the St_SnapToGrid would return true too, so I was surprised when I saw that it didn't work in PostGIS 2.5.3 but worked in PostGIS 3.0

Comment: @user30184 what do you use to see the coordinates without the floating point rounding?

Comment: I was using OpenJUMP for sending your SQL and checked the coordinates of the vertices with OpenJUMP as well.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer how to make the ST_Equals(ST_SnapToGrid... to give a correct result but hopefully it is useful to know how to use OpenJUMP for debugging.

OpenJUMP GIS is quite handy for making queries from PostGIS and for debugging geometries. For your use case the SQL queries can be run with the Run Datastore Query tool. These two separate queries create two new layers

```
SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000004000000606E3D4100000000502156410400000040703D4100000000502156410400000040703D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D41000000009C20564104000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry
SELECT '010600002091080000010000000103000000010000000500000000000000606E3D4100000000502156410000000040703D4100000000502156410000000040703D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D41000000009C20564100000000606E3D410000000050215641'::geometry
```

[image]

The geometries can be checked as WKT from the attribute view or with the feature info tool. Here I used a third method by drawing a fence and checking the vertices within the fence with a tool that if found through the righ-click menu.

[image]